# Order of architecture headers in fat (universal) executables

Tags: binary-analysis, executable, osx, binary-format, mach-o

I'm working on a reverse engineering project with fat executables on OS X. So far I have established the structure of the `fat_header`, `fat_arch` and `macho_header`, but am having trouble finding documentation about the ordering of the `fat_arch` sections. Right now my project works by assuming that `fat_arch` sections appear in order of ascending offset fields. Is this assumption correct, or can the `fat_arch` sections appear in any order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reliable resource which gives an answer to the concrete question if a order exists or not. The question is why would you expect a fixed order of `fat_arch` sections?

The kernel simply loads the Universal Binary at execution time, parses the `fat_arch` structure(s) and selects a matching architecture type. So in my understanding there is no need for a fixed (or expectable) order of the `fat_arch` sections.